# Does buying Komplete 8 help me at all if I already own Ableton?

Tags: ableton

Don't yell at me for asking a stupid question if this is dumb.

I just started making music and I have been using Ableton the whole time. I was going to buy a Maschine controller so I can stop using my mouse and saw that there is some discount if I also get Komplete. However, I don't really understand what Komplete is I think. The impression that I get is it a collection of samples for various instruments.

So what kind of benefits will Komplete give me if I am using Ableton and a Maschine controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Komplete includes a *lot* of samples, but it also includes several great synths and some effects.

Some specifics:

- **FM8** is a six-operator FM synth with arbitrary routings (including feedback) for all operators. Much more powerful than Operator, but also more complicated to get your head around.
- **Massive** and **Absynth** are powerful subtractive synths that go well beyond what Analog can do.
- **Reaktor** is what got me into Komplete in the first place. It is a highly flexible modular environment with a *great* library of synths and FX. Reaktor alone is worth the price of admission, though FM8, Massive and Absynth are faster to work with when they do what you need.
- **Guitar Rig** is a box of guitar pedal simulators. Great for quickly trying out FX. Despite the name, Guitar Rig is GREAT for use with synths.

That said, you can do a *lot* with the synths and FX included in Live. If you aren't sure why you need Komplete (or, anything, really) then don't buy it until you do. NI tends to release new versions of Komplete frequently, so it is possible that K9 is just around the corner.

Answer (score 1):

Komplete is a collection of samplers (Kontakt and Battery), synthesizers (Massive, Absynth, Reaktor (which contains a few), and FM8), and effects (Guitar Rig).

These are all off the top of my head. If you like those items, then I'd buy it. If you only want one or two of those, you can get those separately and not have to buy everything. If you are in no need of any of those, then don't buy it. From what I understand, Ableton comes with a lot to work with by default.